# How can I see a list of class properties in ios8 documentation

Tags: iphone, ios8

It seems that Apple always trying to innovate, which is good, frequently makes an over the top effort breaking what was good before. One sample of this is API documentation.

Now with iOS8 the documentation is missing a section where it groups all properties of a class. Before iOS8, there was this section in the left part of the screen, where one could just click on it and see all the class' properties grouped.
The only -bad- workaround I found was to do a search for @property inside the documentation class, which is an awful documentation design.

Has anybody else found a better way to list all the properties of a class other than doing a search for @property?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the documentation in xcode?

If so, when you click on a key-word in the right section you can see all what you need. The section is call "Quick Help" and is a question mark in a circle.

Otherwise you can click on the key-word with the cmd button pressed, and xcode will bring you into the definition of that word.

Hope it help.

Comment: Yes, this is regarding ios documentation in xcode. That right section is called Quick Help and though it shows some quick help, it doesn't show the properties for the clicked class. If I option-click on the class, say UIViewController, then a floating window shows with the same quick help text; if I then click on the "UIViewController Class Reference" link then documentation opens but as I said in my original question, there's no easy way to see all the @properties grouped as in previous versions of xcode –nor a list of methods for that matter too. I already filed a bug.